# Change ssh tunnel direction with the same port?

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm using an ssh tunnel to forward a port to a db server.
Let's say I'm using mysql, so my ssh command would be something along the lines of
`ssh -fqTN -L 12345:127.0.0.1:3306 user@server.com`

based on the method of transfer (sync from or sync to) I want to use either the -L or -R flags.
I do need the -L flag at first though, so I open the tunnel above anyway.

My question is though -
If after now run 
`ssh -fqTN -R 12345:127.0.0.1:3306 user@server.com`
Will it replace the above command and make a reverse tunnel on the same port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second command will not "replace" the first command, but it will work just fine.

You started with:

```
ssh -fqTN -L 12345:127.0.0.1:3306 user@server.com
```

This opens port `12345` on your local system and forwards it to `127.0.0.1:3306` from the perspective of the remote system, so that you can access the mysql server on the remote system using local port `12345`.

The second command...

```
 ssh -fqTN -R 12345:127.0.0.1:3306 user@server.com
```

...opens port `12345` on the *remote* system and forwards it to `127.0.0.1:3306` from the perspective of your *local* system, allowing the remote system to access a mysql server on your local host via port `12345`.

This doesn't conflict with the original command, so these can both be run at the same time.

**Update**

Responding to your comment here, because I want to quote some command output:

If I run:

```
ssh -R 12345:127.0.0.1:3306 remote_system
```

Then on `remote_system` I run `lsof -i -n`, I see:

```
sshd      23280      lars   10u  IPv6 37263762      0t0  TCP [::1]:italk (LISTEN)
sshd      23280      lars   11u  IPv4 37263763      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:italk (LISTEN)
```

And from `/etc/services`, we see that `italk` is port `12345`.  If you add `-P` to your `lsof` command line it will not try to translate port numbers to service names:

```
# lsof -i -n -P | grep 12345
sshd      23280      lars   10u  IPv6 37263762      0t0  TCP [::1]:12345 (LISTEN)
sshd      23280      lars   11u  IPv4 37263763      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:12345 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Oddly enough, using `sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>'` didn't show the port 12345 open on the remote system. Why is that...? Further - can I reverse tunnel from a system with only an ssh client and have the remote system have access to it?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a response to the first part of your comment.  Regarding your second question, you can specify both `-R` and `-L` on the same command line, so I think you can do what you're asking...but I am not 100% clear on what you are asking, so possibly I am mistaken.